# MVC custom serialization of List<X> parameter for GET request?

Tags: list, model-view-controller, serialization, get, actionresult

I'm wanting to change a request to be GET instead of POST so users can share the generated URLs.
The current system uses a normal form submit and takes advantage of the automatic serialization between the form submit and the MVC ActionResult for a List of custom objects.

e.g.

```
<form action="/MyPage">
  <input type="hidden" id="MyThings_0__Value" name="MyThings[0].Value">
  <input type="hidden" id="MyThings_0__Flag" name="MyThings[0].Flag">

  <input type="hidden" id="MyThings_1__Value" name="MyThings[1].Value">
  <input type="hidden" id="MyThings_1__Flag" name="MyThings[1].Flag">
</form>
```

However doing it this way causes the GET string generated to be overly long and complicated. This is bad because the `MyThings` list can be up to 10 items long.

```
http://myurl.com/MyPage?MyThings%5B0%5D.Value=ThisIsValue1&MyThings%5B0%5D.Flag=1&MyThings%5B1%5D.Value=ThisIsValue2&MyThings%5B1%5D.Flag=2
```

I was hoping for the string to appear more user-friendly. Something like:

```
http://myurl.com/MyPage?MyThings=ThisIsValue1-1,ThisIsValue2-2
```

Can this be done with custom serialization? And if so, how would I go about implementing it?

**My Model and ActionResult**:

```
namespace MyNamespace {

    public class MyThing {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public int Flag { get; set; }
    }

    public class Filter {
        public string CustomAttribute1 { get; set; }
        public string CustomAttribute2 { get; set; }
        public string CustomAttribute3 { get; set; }

        public List<MyThing> MyThings { get; set; } = new List<MyThing>();
    }

    public ActionResult MyPage(Filter filter) {
        MyModel model = StaticMethod.GetMyModel(filter);
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided against using custom URL serialization and used helper methods to convert to string/class backward and forwards within the C# model.

```
public class Filter {

    public string MyThing { get; set; }

    public List<MyThingClass> MyThings {
        get {
            if (this._myThings == null) { // Default to Query string
                this._myThings = ToQueryList(this.MyThing);
            }
            return this._myThings;
        }
        set {
            this.MyThing = ToQueryString(value); // Automatically assign QueryString to serialized QueryItems on set
            this._myThings = value;
        }
    }
    private List<MyThingClass> _myThings { get; set; }

    public static List<MyThingClass> ToQueryList(string queryString) {
        return queryString.Split(',').Select(x => MyThingClass.FromString(x)).ToList();
    }
    public static string ToQueryString(List<MyThingClass> myThings) {
        return string.Join(",", myThings.Select(x => x.ToString()));
    }
}



public class MyThingClass {

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int Flag { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Converts a QueryItem object to a serialized object ready for the QueryString.</summary>
    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Concat(this.Value, "-", this.Flag);
    }

    public static MyThingClass FromString(string value) {
        var v = value.Split('-');
        return new MyThingClass() {
            Value = v[0],
            Flag = Convert.ToInt32(v[1])
        };
    }
}
```